# How to clear space in Bitbucket repository that's over size limit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am pushing my iOS app code to Bitbucket, and it's given me the error:

```
Repository is in read only mode (over 2 GB size limit).
```

I've realised I have been pushing some files (Pod files, if you know what that is) to Bitbucket when actually I don't need to. I now want to clear up space in Bitbucket by deleting the folder `/Pods` from the repository.

I have also added this to my `.gitignore`:

```
/Pods/*
```

which I'm hoping means it will ignore the Pods folder and all that's in it. I have some committed changes that it won't let me push because of the read-only mode. I tried deleting the Pods folder from my local machine and pushing that but that won't work either. How can I:

1. Push these committed changes
2. Get my Bitbucket repository out of read-only mode by deleting the `/Pods` folder.
3. Make sure that Bitbucket ignores the `/Pods` folder in the future

Incidentally, I'm using SourceTree for my repository handling, but willing to use the command line if necessary to get me out of this mess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: Check out the link I provided in my previous comment. It explains how to permanently remove files from your repo.

Comment: Thanks but that leaves a lot of unanswered questions - what happens to my pushed files, how can I delete specific folders, is my gitignore correct, etc.

Comment: git knows nothing about folders. In order to delete a folder, just delete all the files in it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There's about 4000 files inside different folders inside that one folder though.

Comment: you can delete them all pretty easily with a single `git rm` command